# JDBC - query does not return data after where statement

Tags: java, jdbc

Okay. Here's a piece of code that should return an array after searching a database
with JDBC. It's the Apache Derby database that's built into the JDK.

```
import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class readnames {

static Object [] name;
static Object [] type;
static Object [] desc;
static ArrayList<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> l2 = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> l3 = new ArrayList<String>();

public static Object[] lies(String desq) {

    final String DRIVER = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";

    final String CONNECTION = "jdbc:derby:AccountDatabase";

    try {
    Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION);
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from WARPS WHERE CATEGORY=?");
        statement.setString(1, "Server");
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery();
            if (resultset.next()) {
                    while(resultset.next()) {
                        l.add(resultset.getString("NAME"));
                          l2.add(resultset.getString("CATEGORY"));  
                        l3.add(resultset.getString("DESCRIP"));
                    }
                    name = l.toArray();
                    type = l2.toArray();
                    desc = l3.toArray();
                    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
                        System.out.println(name[i]);
                    }
                    for (int i2= 0; i2 < type.length; i2++) {
                        System.out.println(type[i2]);
                    }
                    for (int i3= 0; i3 < desc.length; i3++) {
                        System.out.println(desc[i3]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("The method is called");
            } else {System.out.println("No entries exist in this category");
            }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return name;
} 

}
```

My problem is, it doesn't return anything at all. It worked fine until I tried filtering the data using a PreparedStatement with a WHERE-clause in it. But I really don't want to get ALL the data, but specific data. The calls to println were added for debug purposes; nothing is printed when the where-clause is in the code.

EDIT: The l2.add and l3.add clauses in the while-loop are also just for debug purposes. Sry.

btw, the data that I want to retrieve definetely is in the database and gets printed when I delete the where-clause.

Does anyone know what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try  to run the same query against the database to validate ?

Comment: Test if the query <select * from WARPS WHERE CATEGORY='Server'> return results using SQL client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your query is returning exactly one row but you're skipping it.  This line:

```
if (resultset.next()) {
```

advances the `ResultSet` to the first row.  But then your next statement

```
while(resultset.next()) {
```

advances it to the next row, which probably does not exist.

You should have only the `while` loop; remove the `if`.  You can set a `boolean` variable to `true` within the `while` loop so that you can tell if you had records and later print `"No entries exist in this category"` if there weren't any rows.

Answer (score 2):

try this, don't use if and while, try to use if and do while;

```
if (resultset.next()) {
do {
    l.add(resultset.getString("NAME"));
      l2.add(resultset.getString("CATEGORY"));  
    l3.add(resultset.getString("DESCRIP"));
}while(resultset.next());
name = l.toArray();
type = l2.toArray();
desc = l3.toArray();
for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
    System.out.println(name[i]);
}
for (int i2= 0; i2 < type.length; i2++) {
    System.out.println(type[i2]);
}
for (int i3= 0; i3 < desc.length; i3++) {
    System.out.println(desc[i3]);
}
System.out.println("The method is called");
} else {System.out.println("No entries exist in this category");}
```

and in query write.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION);
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from WARPS WHERE lower(CATEGORY)=?");
statement.setString(1, "Server".toLowerCase());
```

don't forget to use string functions which using where clause.

Answer (score 2):

If your result just has 1 row, you are going to not get anything.

The reason:

```
if (resultset.next()) {  
                    while(resultset.next()) {
```

When you do a `.next()` in the `` `while ``, the cursor has already been advanced once by `if`.
You should just be doing

```
while(resultset.next()) {
```

this does not execute if there are no rows.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you surround your while with an if statement? The condition moves the resultset one row forward so you're missing the first row. If there aren't any rows left the while statement will exit by itself. The if surrounding it is not required.